# Api call and show data with RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit to get list of pallet types from Api.
This is how my call looks like.

```
@GET("pallettypes")
Observable<List<PalletType>> getPalletTypes();
```

Then I have some function that gets the response from the api and map it (I don't know if I'm using the map function as it should - new to RxJava)

```
private static Observable<List<PalletType>> getTypes() {
return getApiService().getPalletTypes()
                .map(response -> {
//Here i need some code to get the response from the api and put it in Store.palletTypes()
            }
            return response;
```

And then to call the function in the onViewCreated part.

```
 getTypes().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                  .doOnSubscribe(() ->{
                  })
                  .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                  })
                  .subscribe(response -> {
                      PalletsManager.getInstance().setTypes(response);
                      populateTypes(response);
                  }, throwable -> {
                  });
```

I need populateTypes function to show the type using a custom view

```
public void populateTypes (List<PalletType> palletTypes) {
    for(PalletType type : palletTypes) {
        palletView = new PalletView(getContext());
        palletView.setLabel(type.getType());
        delivered_pallets.addView(palletView);
    }
}
```

This is my idea but it doesn't work because I never get in the .subscribe block and noting is shown.

Comment: Remove throwable -> {} and show your exception which will be thrown

Comment: What exception are you getting in throwable

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.

Comment: Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: HTTP 404 Not Found
Caused by: retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.HttpException: HTTP 404 Not Found

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys I found my error it was in the Api call.